# How to implement CSRF protection for GET requests in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

How do I implement CSRF protection using built-in Express middleware for HTTP GET requests?

For instance, user logout often made via GET request and actually change state of web application so it should be protected against CSRF.

Unfortunately, CSRF middleware ignores HTTP GET and doesn't export helpers to manually check token.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, they now expose the way of explicitly setting which methods to ignore

```
app.use(csurf({ignoreMethods: ['HEAD', 'OPTIONS']}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom fork of the Connect CSRF middleware that would not ignore GET requests. The line that does so is here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/csrf.js#L76

However, don't do it. GET requests are safe and idempotent: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

In other words, no one is worried that a malicious web script might log them out from a site. The worry is that it could post spam in your name or transfer money out of your bank account. That's what you need CSRF to protect against. Lots more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf

Comment: Handling every GET request is definitely a bad idea cause most of them don't change the state (or idempotent, whatever). I wonder if I can do it in one particular case.

Comment: If you're worried about malicious logout (which I don't think is a realistic concern), you'd do better to change just that to require a POST.